# There is no group with exactly three elements of order 3

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Prove that there is no group that has exactly three elements of order 3.

Please can someone kindly put me through how to prove this?

I know that a group of three elements = {x,y,z}. but proving that no group of exactly three elements exists is my problem.

Comment: AN  ELEMENT  OF  ORDER 3  IS  DIFFERENT  OF  HIS  INVERSE.

Comment: The question doesn't ask for a group with three elements (there's the cyclic group $C_3$), but for a group of unspecified size where exactly three of the elements have order $3$.

Comment: Be careful with your definitions here. The order of an element of a group is not the same as the order of the group. The order of an element g is the smallest positive integer k such that g^k = e. That is different from the order of the group, which is the number of elements it contains.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** An element has exactly the same order as its inverse. And an element of order $3$ is not its own inverse.

Comment: can i say <x> = {e, x, x^-1} as a group of order three

Comment: @Atinuke: It is a _group of order three_, but only two of its three _elements_ have order three.

Answer (score 2):

Try to make the multiplication table for a group of three elements, it should not be difficult. Think about the inverse for each element as well as each of its powers.

Comment: pls put me through the table pls.

Answer (score 0):

Every group has the identity element $e$ which always has order $1$ so there goes that.